# How to use CASE and Between in where condition for a year in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, case, between

I have a following data
[image]

Now If oh_year_to have word Current then i have to use it as current year and if there is year written then it should consider as what is written on the column

so i am trying to check a following query but it does give me error

```
SELECT "oh_new_make"
    FROM public.make_override_history 
    CASE 
      WHEN oh_year_to = 'CURRENT' 
       ('2020' BETWEEN "oh_year_from" AND '2020') 
      ELSE
       ('2020' BETWEEN "oh_year_from" AND "oh_year_to") 
    GROUP BY "oh_new_make"
```

Basically i want all the new_makes which falls in 2020. this query is giving me error at the value i am passing

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as:

```
where oh_year_from 
    between '2020' 
    and case when oh_year_to = 'CURRENT' then '2020' else oh_year_to end
```

You could also use boolean logic:

```
where 
    oh_year_from <= '2020' 
    and (oh_year_to = 'CURRENT' or (oh_year_to <> 'CURRENT' and oh_year_to >= '2020')
```

Note that using string comparison here is rather tricky - if you had `oh_year_to` set to `3`, the condition would succeed (because, string-wise, `'3'` is greater than `'2020'`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use relatively simple comparison logic:

```
where oh_year_from <= '2020' and
      (oh_year_to = 'CURRENT' or oh_year_to <= '2020')
```

I think your trying to use `between` is making the logic more complicated.